# Managing scopes and permissions

Tags: database-design

I have the following database:

[image: Database Design Diagram]

## DB EXPLANATION

- Each user can be assigned multiple projects and scopes.
- Each user can only be assigned one role.
- Scopes are shared, so multiple roles can have the same scopes.
- I created the `roles` table with the idea of creating user tiers (Admin, Registered, VIP, etc.).
- Users get roles assigned on the `user_roles` table.
- Roles get scopes assigned on the `role_scopes` table.
- Users get projects assigned on the `user_projects` table.

## EXAMPLE DATA

Here you have a SQL to create the tables on a `MySQL` database and populate them with sample data:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`roles` (
  `role_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projects` (
  `project_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`user_projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user_projects` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `project_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `project_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_projects_projects1_idx` (`project_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_user_projects_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_projects_projects1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`projects` (`project_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_projects_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`user_roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user_roles` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `role_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `role_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_roles_roles1_idx` (`role_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_user_roles_user_projects1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_roles_roles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`roles` (`role_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_roles_user_projects1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`scopes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`scopes` (
  `scope_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scope_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`role_scopes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`role_scopes` (
  `role_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `scope_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`, `scope_id`),
  INDEX `fk_role_scopes_roles1_idx` (`role_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_role_scopes_scopes1_idx` (`scope_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_role_scopes_roles`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`roles` (`role_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_role_scopes_scopes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`scope_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`users` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'admin');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`users` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'user1');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`users` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'user2');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`roles` (`role_id`, `code`) VALUES (1, 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`roles` (`role_id`, `code`) VALUES (2, 'REGISTERED');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`projects` (`project_id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Project 1');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`projects` (`project_id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Project 2');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`projects` (`project_id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Project 3');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`user_projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_projects` (`user_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (3, 3);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`user_roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_roles` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_roles` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user_roles` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES (3, 2);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`scopes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (1, 'project:view');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (2, 'project:edit');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (3, 'project:delete');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (4, 'user:edit');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (5, 'user:create');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`scopes` (`scope_id`, `code`) VALUES (6, 'user:delete');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`role_scopes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (1, 6);
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`role_scopes` (`role_id`, `scope_id`) VALUES (2, 4);

COMMIT;
```

## PROBLEM

I need to limit what users can do within each project. A user can be in 2 projects and have different scopes on each one of them. And 10 users can be on the same project, but not necessarily have the same scopes for that project.

I can think of the following ways to do this:

- Create a `project_permissions` table that will store a `user_id` and a `scope_id`.
- Create a `groups` table, create a `project_groups` table and assign scopes via a `group_scopes` table. Then, via a `user_groups` table, assign users to the groups.

I want to do this in such a way that in the future I can create different 'objects' (a project would be an example of an 'object' in my app) and assign scopes to the users assigned to those 'objects' (same way I want to assign scopes to the projects).

## QUESTION

What would be the best option to implement? Is there a better way (maybe even simpler) to do this?